# Ruby and other languages(Python, JavaScript) different hmac sha256 result

Tags: javascript, python, ruby

I have Ruby 2.5.3 code that create hmac with sha256

```rb
require 'openssl'

key = '4629de5def93d6a2abea6afa9bd5476d9c6cbc04223f9a2f7e517b535dde3e25'
message = 'lucas'
hash = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('sha256', key, message)

hash => ba2e2505c6f302fb3c40bea4491d95bacd96c3d12e8fbe50197ca431165fcee2
```

But the result is different from Python & JavaScript code. What should I do in Ruby code to have the same result as from the others?

Python

```py
import hmac
import hashlib
import binascii

message = "lucas"
key = "4629de5def93d6a2abea6afa9bd5476d9c6cbc04223f9a2f7e517b535dde3e25"
hash = hmac.new(
    binascii.unhexlify(bytearray(key, "utf-8")),
    msg=message.encode('utf-8'),
    digestmod=hashlib.sha256
).hexdigest()

hash => 99427c7bba36a6902c5fd6383f2fb0214d19b81023296b4bd6b9e024836afea2
```

JavaScript

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

const message = 'lucas';
const key = '4629de5def93d6a2abea6afa9bd5476d9c6cbc04223f9a2f7e517b535dde3e25';

const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', Buffer.from(key, 'hex'))
                .update(message)
                .digest('hex');

hash => 99427c7bba36a6902c5fd6383f2fb0214d19b81023296b4bd6b9e024836afea2
```

Comment: Comparing it to an online tool (https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/hmac-sha256-online) it looks to me that the ruby version is correct and python and js are wrong. Not the other way around.

Comment: In Python and JS you are using the "key" as hexstring, means that the hexstring is converted to a binary format. In Ruby the key is used without conversion.

Comment: @MichaelFehr Oh! You're certainly right!

Answer (score 1):

> In Python and JS you are using the "key" as hexstring, means that the hexstring is converted to a binary format. In Ruby the key is used without conversion. – Michael Fehr

This gave me the solution.

```rb
key = '4629de5def93d6a2abea6afa9bd5476d9c6cbc04223f9a2f7e517b535dde3e25'
message = 'lucas'
puts OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('sha256', [key].pack('H*') , message)

hash => 99427c7bba36a6902c5fd6383f2fb0214d19b81023296b4bd6b9e024836afea2
```

thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help you.